# Redirect Users from China (based on IP) to a specific URL

Tags: wordpress, apache, redirect, ip

I have a wordpress site on an apache server on AWS. I would like to redirect a user to a specific url if the user's IP is coming from China. My questions are:

1. Where do I set up this redirect? Options that I am thinking of are: tweaking apache config files, or editing certain php files in the wordpress application, or installing some wordpress plugiin.
2. How do I know if a user's IP is coming from China using code? I can look up an individual IP on the internet one by one to geo locate it, but how do I determine at runtime?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please install [IP2Location](http://www.ip2location.com/developers/apache) Apache Module

Update .htaccess file as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:IP2LOCATION_COUNTRY_SHORT} ^CN$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.redirecturl.com [L]
```